# I can't go back to macOS after successfully installing Win 10 from Boot Camp Assistant

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup

I have a iMac running macOS High Sierra.  I ran Boot Camp Assistant on it and was able to switch to Win 10, successfully, without any problem.  I downloaded the ISO file for Win 10, and used the USB drive as requested.

However, when I try to switch back to macOS, with the "alt" key held down while restarting Win 10, I never see the screen which shows the different operating systems to choose from. Instead, every restart takes me right back to Windows OS, like it's just a regular Window restart action.

Comment: Also, while running Win 10, my system has no sound!  I checked and updated all Media drivers on the Imac, and eveything are fine and up to date.  Thanks again.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! Could you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/368736/edit) your question to confirm what keyboard you're using and what, if anything, you've already tried? (Otherwise you risk getting lots of suggestions for things you've already done). Finally, what happens if you fully shutdown from Windows and then power up while holding the option key? Or, while restarting from the Boot Camp icon in the Windows task bar?

Comment: I use a universal wireless logitech keyboard, and this is the only keyboard I've tried.  I tried fully shutdown from Windows and holding the "alt" key when power up, yet the problem still persist, it'll just take me back to Window, like before.  I don't see any boot camp icon in the Windows task bar.  I tried to look for it in the settings app to see if it's been hidden, but still, can't find it on the list in the Personalization tab.

Comment: Okay, firstly refer to [Start up your Mac in Windows or macOS with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-control-panel/bcmp29b8ac66/mac) to see if that sheds any light on things (it also shows what the Boot Camp icon looks like). Secondly, if nothing on that page helps, do you have access to an Apple keyboard you can test with (just to see what difference, if any, that makes?